# Scaling EC2 instance with updated code

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance which is running a PHP website,I am using the scaling policies of AWS as well, which means that when certain conditions are met a new instance is spawned.

The problem is that the AMI is spawned with old AMI code.

Suppose I created `instance1` with `AMI X`. Now I update code on instance1 time to time. Now when a new instance is spawned it is created with AMI X code, not with the updates I made.

What is the solution for current scenario apart from updating AMI manually each time?

Answer (score 0):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is a read-only copy of the disk image that will be used to start a new Amazon EC2 instance. Any new instance launched from that AMI will have exactly the same boot disk.

You are correct that if you update code on an instance, this will not impact the underlying AMI. Any future instances started from the same AMI will not have the updated code, since those changes did not impact the AMI.

There are several options if you want future instances to have updated code:

- Update the code, then **create a new AMI**. Start future instances from the new AMI.
- Use a **startup script** in the User Data field to download the code from a central repository. This way, the code isn't actually stored on the AMI. It can be downloaded afresh every time an instance is started.
- Use a **configuration management utility** such as Puppet or Chef to configure your system, pulling code from a central repository.

The key is to automate your processes so that no manual involvement is required when you wish to roll-out updates.

Comment: do you have any example of ready-made script, since I dont know about the user data field.

Comment: The script can do whatever you wish. The simplest would be to download a zip file from S3 with all your code, unzip it, then execute it. User Data documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html